# Django dynamic form rendering

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I'm stuck with a task I have currently with django. There are plenty of tutorials on creating dynamic forms but my problem is more about getting a proper HTML.

I have several model instances, let is be

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    field1=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    field2=models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

What I need is to show user an HTML page whith multiple forms representing several SomeModel instances. 
The problem is I wish that only some of the forms will give user an opportunity to enter only field1, some will only allow to enter field2 and some give both.

For the fields I don't wish to be editable I want to present it's content as a label. So, for instance in my database I have tree SomeModel instances that have field1 and field2 ('aaa','bbb'), ('cccc','dddd') and ('eeeee','fffff'). And I have information that I want only field1 editable in first instance, on the second only field 2 is editable, and it is allowed to edit both field1 and field2.

The HTML that renders it I want looks like somewhat like this

```
<form method="post" action="">
 <input name="some_model_id" type="hidden" value="0"> 
 <label>some Model 0 field1</label><input type="text" name="someModel-0-field1" value="aaa" id="id_form-0-title" />  
<label>bbb</label>

<input name="some_model_id" type="hidden" value="1"> 
<label>cccc</label>
<label>some Model 1 field2</label><input type="text" name="someModel-1-field2" value="dddd" id="id_form-0-title" />  

<input name="some_model_id" type="hidden" value="2"> 
<label>some Model 2 field1</label><input type="text" name="someModel-2-field1" value="eeeee" id="id_form-0-title" />  
<label>some Model 2 field2</label><input type="text" name="someModel-2-field2" value="fffff" id="id_form-0-title" />  

<input name="Submit" type=submit value="Submit">  
</form>
```

I want to have the reciving the data from the forms as django usualy does, validation, etc.
I know for several forms there are formsets, but I don't know how to use them here. 
Also I wish I could first create a form and then say what I want to edit instead of passing this information to __init__.

What is the pythonic way to implement this?
Thank you!